# GCE: Is there access to the maintenance shell?

Tags: shell, google-compute-engine, fsck

One of my instances is having trouble with a disk.  The serial console teasingly displays the erro and a console prompt:

```
fsck.ext4: No such file or directory while trying to open /dev/sdbt
Possibly non-existent device?
fsck died with exit status 8
[?25l[?1c7[1G[[31mFAIL[39;49m8[?25h[?0c[31mfailed (code 8).[39;49m
[....] File system check failed. A log is being saved in /var/log/fsck/checkfs if that location is writable. Please repair the file system manually. ...[?25l[?1c7[1G[[31mFAIL[39;49m8[?25h[?0c [31mfailed![39;49m
[....] A maintenance shell will now be started. CONTROL-D will terminate this shell and resume system boot. ...[?25l[?1c7[1G[[33mwarn[39;49m8[?25h[?0c [33m(warning).[39;49m
sulogin: root account is locked, starting shell
root@(none):~#
```

Is there any way to make the serial console interactive?  It'd be great to look at the fstab file for starters, or even hit ctl-D to kick it along.

Also can anything be done to cleanup the gibberish on the console?

Comment: Any way to view or modify files on a GCE instance that can't come up past single user mode, or is it completely hosed even if I can see the serial console prompt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can shutdown the instance but not delete its boot disk.  Then you can create a new instance; click on "Show advanced options" during the instance creation, and you will be presented the option to add "ADDITIONAL DISKS (Optional)."

Attach the disk that needs a fsck as an additional disk.  This way the new instance will be booting off of a clean disk, and you can fsck the other disk as normal.  Assuming everything can be cleaned up, you can go back to using the original disk as a boot disk again.

The gibberish is just the ANSI escape sequences used to color the output on a terminal.

Comment: That makes sense to me.  But the only two shutdown options are 'sudo poweroff' or 'gcutil deleteinstance'.  Since I can't ssh in, the only option is the scary looking 'gcutil deleteinstance'.  Hmm.  But I think this is the answer.  Hopefully the persistent disk remains and it's not a hardware issue.

Comment: The persistent disk will only be deleted if you selected [auto-deletion](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/disks#attachdiskcreation) when you created the instance.  Otherwise, there is a (y/n) prompt to confirm the instance deletion, and a separate (y/n) prompt for persistent disk deletion.

Comment: Thanks Charles.  The root of the issue was a typo in an fstab entry.  In my case it was related to /dev/sdbt (the 't' was a typo).  Mounting the disk on another instance allowed me to delete the bad entry and the disk booted successfully.